# Design data transfer object depending on ui logic

Tags: c#, dto, data-transfer-objects

I am in a situation with data transfer objects where I start thinking I am over-architecting or complicating things...

I dunno wether I am right or wrong.

All the properties down in the EditSchoolyearDTO are only needed when WeekType AB is selected in the client side UI.

When only WeekType A is selected then the A-properties are enough.

In the AB-Case I would create now a SchoolWeekADTO and SchoolWeekBDTO.

Well when I consider the DTO structure as json interface between my client and server then my DTO structure does not express when the A or AB data is needed. This feels bad for me.

Above all my server api has a fixed type so I can not at one time send a post with a A-DTO and at another time a AB-DTO.

What would you do?

```
public class EditSchoolyearDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public WeekType StartWeek { get; set; }
        public enum WeekType : int
        {
            A = 0,
            AB = 1,
        }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public SchoolWeekADTO SchoolWeekA { get; set; }
        public SchoolWeekBDTO SchoolWeekB { get; set; }

        // When WeektType is A then only SchoolWeekA is or its A-properties are needed
        // SchoolyWeekADTO
        //public int MaxPeriodPerWeekA { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<int> VisibleWeekDayIndexA;
        //public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeekA { get; set; }

        // SchoolWeekBDTO
        //public int WeeklyRotation { get; set; }
        //public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeekB { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<int> VisibleWeekDayIndexB;
        //public int MaxPeriodPerWeekB { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: can UI change the value of StartWeek? if yes, do you need to dynamically pull the related information for AB data?

Comment: Qestion1: Yes the UI can select between WeekType A or AB. I do need nothing actually... It just does make sense to me to send data in the form of a dto where each property is used in the current context. If the context is WeekType A then it does not make sense to have 4 properties which are Null even more I would have to make them Nullable<int> etc...

Comment: Is this a DTO that you send from a client to the server or the other way round?

Comment: I personally never came across this situation and I think it is mainly because I always take full advantage of object oriented design even in my DTO. That being said, IMHO it is perfectly valid to have properties in DTO that are null. Because if your UI is dynamic enough to change types you should provide the properties to bind to the UI fields. You can specify in your serialization to not include the null values in JSON objects.

Comment: @Szymon from the client to the server.

Comment: @Aidin But you can not dynamically annotate a c# property with [NoSerialization] depending on a client side value... my code is not less then OOP I think.

Comment: I didnt mean to ignore the field altogether. Usually there is an option in serializers that if and only if a field value is Null, then serializer will ignore that field; otherwise, would serialize the field. I use Json.NET and through that you can handle all kind of custom serializations: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it not necessary to send all objects and also mark the intention of the client better, you could separate the properties for type A and B into separate classes. This way you always select one of the values of the enum to say if the type is A or B. Base on that you create an instance of one of `WeekTypeADTO` and `WeekTypeBDTO` and set the other to `null`.

The code also looks cleaner and shows your intention better.

```
public class EditSchoolyearDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public WeekType StartWeek { get; set; }
    public enum WeekType : int
    {
        A = 0,
        AB = 1,
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public WeekTypeADTO SchoolWeekA { get; set; }
    public WeekTypeBDTO SchoolWeekB { get; set; }

}

public class WeekTypeADTO
{
    public int MaxPeriodPerWeekA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> VisibleWeekDayIndexA {get; set;}
    public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeekA { get; set; }
}

public class WeekTypeBDTO
{
    public int WeeklyRotation { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeekB { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> VisibleWeekDayIndexB {get; set;}
    public int MaxPeriodPerWeekB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hehe thats smart of you to take my code and the commented code and put it inside my suggested class names :P But this approach is at least better than make 4 AB properties nullable types...

Comment: Well, as you were almost there in my opinion, didn't want to change your code too much.